# Comparing Enum values for sorting

Tags: c#, sorting, enums, comparison

In a project I have an external enum (generated from a service reference).
So I cannot change the enum values.

How can I compare those enum values to each other in an effective way?

Here an example for an enum

```
public enum Values
{
    A,
    B,
    C,
    D,
    E,
    F,
    G,
    H
}
```

And the sortorder I want them is not the same (something like F, H, A, C, B, ...)

Right now I have a extension method with some comparisons.
(having another enum with the order I want)

```
public static int CompareTo(this Values x, Values y)
    {
        var orderedX = GetOrderedValues(x);
        var orderedY = GetOrderedValues(y);

        return orderedX.CompareTo(orderedY);
    }


internal enum ValuesOrdered
{
    F = 0,
    H = 1,
    C = 2,
    D = 3,
    B = 4,
    A = 5,
    E = 6,
    G = 7
}

internal static ValuesOrdered GetOrderedValues(this Values x)
{
    switch (x)
    {
        case Values.A:
        {
           return ValuesOrdered.A;
        }

        // and so on...
    }
}
```

Can this be achieved more effective?

Comment: Your approach seems reasonable. When you don't have control of the source values, sometimes you have to get by with a less than optimal solution.

Comment: What does this extension method do? How are you using it? What's the significance of `CompareTo` and why do you show a trivial implementation that always returns 0?

Comment: Will try to answer your questions in an edit of the question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Override Enum Type Consuming Web Service](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5562539/override-enum-type-consuming-web-service)

Comment: Hope my question is more precise now.

Comment: Override Enum Type is not a duplicate, but has to do with it, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If all you want to do is `CompareTo`, then I think you could simplify this a bit by using a dictionary:

```
static Dictionary<Values, int> order = new Dictionary<Values, int>
{
    {Values.A, 3},
    {Values.B, 5},
    {Values.C, 4},
    {Values.D, 6},
    {Values.E, 8},
    {Values.F, 1},
    {Values.G, 7},
    {Values.H, 2}
};

public static int CompareTo(this Values x, Values y)
{
    return order[x].CompareTo(order[y]);
}
```

**However**, I'm not sure why want to implement an extension method named CompareTo, but I hope you *don't* expect it to override the `Enum.CompareTo`. For example,

```
var values = Enum.GetValues(typeof(Values)).Cast<Values>().ToArray();
Array.Sort(values); 
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" ", values)); 
//OUTPUT: A B C D E F G H
```

Comment: Actually I expected it to override it. Have seen this does not work, have forgot about Enum. :-(

Comment: All answers are very good. Accepted yours for pointing the override part out.

Answer (score 5):

I believe the simplest would be to implement your comparison function in this manner:

```
public static int CompareTo(this Values x, Values y)
{
    var sortOrder = new[] {
        Values.F,
        Values.H,
        Values.C,
        Values.D,
        Values.B,
        Values.A,
        Values.E,
        Values.G
    };

    return Array.IndexOf(sortOrder, x) - Array.IndexOf(sortOrder, y);
}
```

Of course you would want to move the initialization of `sortOrder` outside the function so that it only runs once.

Regarding the choice of array as the data structure that encodes the desired ordering: not only is it the simplest, but for such a small number of items linear search is likely also fastest.

Comment: Sounds very good. It is definitly more concise than having another enum!

Answer (score 2):

instead to enum ValuesOrdered use static readonly SortedList (you cannot use constant for SortedList) like this:

```
private static readonly SortedList<Values, int> ordered = new SortedList<Values, int> 
    {
        {Values.F,0},
        {Values.H,1},
        {Values.C,2},
        {Values.D,3},
        {Values.B,4},
        {Values.A,5},
        {Values.E,6},
        {Values.G,7},
    };
```

And method "CompareTo" will be like this:

```
public static int CompareTo(this Values x, Values y)
    {
        return Comparer<int>.Default.Compare(ordered[x], ordered[y]);
    }
```

Enjoy! :-)

Comment: This is the way to go for me. Thank you!